# Crash in MediaPlayer Framework -- [__NSCFString containsObject] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, crash

Crashlytics is reporting crashes in our app. We haven't been able to reproduce this crash on any of our devices. Here is our crash report:

```
**Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException**
**[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17022c5c0**
0 CoreFoundation    __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 60
2 CoreFoundation __methodDescriptionForSelector
3 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___ + 928
4 CoreFoundation    _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5 MediaPlayer   __MPHasAudioBackgroundMode_block_invoke + 260
6 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7 libdispatch.dylib dispatch_once_f + 96
8 MediaPlayer MPHasAudioBackgroundMode + 64
**9 MediaPlayer -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _shouldContinuePlaybackInBackground] + 76**
**10 MediaPlayer -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _canContinuePlayingWhenLocked]** + 80
11 MediaPlayer -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _willResignActiveNotification:] + 32
12 CoreFoundation __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
13 CoreFoundation _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
14 Foundation -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
15 UIKit -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 504
16 UIKit -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2556
```

From lines 9 and 10, it looks like the crash occurs when a user locks the app while the video is playing. Is this a reasonable deduction? As I've mentioned, we haven't been able to reproduce the crash nor have we been able to find anyone else who has had the same problem.

Has anyone experienced this type of crash before?

And, as the crash occurs within Apple's own framework, should we "file a radar" for this?

Has anyone any strategies for debugging a crash like this?

Comment: Can you avoid the crash by pausing or stopping the video in the appWillTerminate delegate call?

Comment: Users might expect the audio to continue playing (like when you listen to a lecture or song on YouTube).